# Drag object inside scrollview and change offset of scrollview accordingly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to implement apple's default icon arrangement process in my application.

in iPhone/iPod Home screen when you drag an icon if that icon comes to right corner then scrollview automatically moves and comes to next page.

I want to implement that feature in my app.

I inserted 3 views inside a scrollview and I am moving a view by using UIPanGestureRecognizer and want to move that scrollview when view comes to right corner.

I put a validation for that and changing contentOffset of scrollview when that subview comes to right corner but problem is that when scrollview changes its offset my control on that view has been removed and

```
[gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
```

is being called automatically.

Anybody knows how app has implemented that feature?

How can I implement this?

Comment: i think the easiest way would be to use the new UICollectionView to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar project that have the same functionality is here

https://github.com/heikomaass/HMLauncherView

You can use it to make your app. *( If you need to solve your problem specifically.... provide code of your touches methods)*

Comment: did you check its demo video.?